# awscli list all objects created by ownerid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-vpc, aws-billing

I'm trying to stay within the limits of my free tier, however, I notice I am being charged ~$1.50 a day for something, I don't know what.

I've terminated all my instances, yet the bill keeps ticking up every day.
I've also deleted all my security groups, route-tables, nat-gateway, subnets and vpc, everything I can think of.  Something is still there creating charges though.

How can I get a list of all the objects still hanging around?

Comment: Have you looked at your invoice? Which service are you being billed for?

Comment: Go to you your user menu (top-right), and select **My Billing Dashboard**.

Comment: It says I still have a NAT gateway and an EC2 instance running somewhere, though I can't find them.  I was hoping there is some aws cli command that will just itemize for me all the items I still have hanging around

Comment: Make sure you check all regions.

Comment: afaict I've deleted everything now, I painstakingly deleted everything I could find- bill is still going up $1 every time I look at it.  Admittedly it's only $3.50 right now, but I'd like to get this thing to stop climbing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a support request to AWS, there are very responsive to the requests. I had a student account on AWS and some Fargate charges were added to my account. I opened a case and submitted a ticket in the support centre. They responded quickly with the reason why my charges were occurring and also gave me $20 USD credit for that month. Also, you can check if [Termination protection](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-cloudformation-provides-stack-termination-protection/) is enabled in any of your stack in CloudFormation. It stops your instances from being deleted.

Comment: you can check termination protection from EC2 instance dashboard it self. @Shilpa  AWS service is so nice without having any support plan they response quickly you are right. they deleted my 282$ bill previous month.

Answer (score 0):

you can contact aws support centre for more info. after deleting all instances and other services wait for 24-48 hour. it will be reflected in billing after that much amount of time.

you can go inside cloud formation and delete all stack if any one is there and check for all region.

also if you created load balancer delete it manually it will be not deleted with EC2 instances.